# When is it appropriate to use a comma before “which”, “with”, and “who”?

Tags: commas, clauses, prepositional-phrases

Is it appropriate to use a comma before *which* in the following sentence?

> The group has helped me to make new friends and become more independent, which has increased my self-confidence.

Is it appropriate to use a comma before *with* or *who* in the following sentence?

> This is an important group, with committed members who enjoy their activities.

I have been looking up restrictive and non-restrictive clauses, and although I understand the theory, I am unsure how to apply it to the two sentences above.

Comment: You forgot _me_ after _helped_. As for the comma, it should be used before any non-restrictive relative clause, like the one starting with _which_. In the second sentence, the restrictive relative has been reduced by converting _which has_ to _with_, from _This is an important group, [`which has` --> `with`] committed members, ..._ Commas should be inserted when you **hear** them, as you do when saying these sentences out loud. Commas are not distributed by the words they come before or after, but rather when they are **pronounced**. If you don't hear'em, don't use'em.

Comment: "Comma is not grammar." That said, I have a feeling this has been touched upon earlier on this site. A search may be worth it.

Comment: If it helps, the first sentence has the required comma in the right place, the second does not need one, whether using *with* or *which has* but a comma there is not wrong. There are other instances where a comma is either clearly necessary or clearly inappropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I now understand that in the first sentence the clause beginning with 'which' is a non-restrictive relative clause because it does not affect the meaning of the sentence if removed.

Comment: @Kris: I'm not so sure a comma is not needed in sentence two. Without the comma, the sentence could mean that only the committed members of the group enjoy the group's activities, and the uncommitted members, not so much. Just a thought. Don